# разъясните по запросу?

Tags: jquery, ajax

вопрос в самом примере, объясните пожалуйста

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "someURL",
  dataType: "text",
  contentType: "application/json",
}).done(function (data) {
  someData = data;//data = '3000'
  console.log('success ' + data);
}).fail(function () {
  alert("some thing wrong with time");    
});
var dataNeed = someData/100;//почему здесь NaN?
```

почему вначале создается переменная, а потом определяется someData? нужно, чтобы dataNeed равнялось вычисленному значению

Comment: Потому что someData определится только после окончания асинхронного запроса. А присвоение происходит сразу после его инициализации

Comment: я приблизительно так и предполагал, а как это поправить?

Comment: Как поправить причинно-следственные связи? Перенести `var dataNeed = ...` в `.done(function(data) { ...`.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: Попробуйте объявить перемеренную someData выше запроса  ajax. И переменная  someData при запуске скорее всего  будет пустой поэтому и NaN

Comment: @Даниил И что будет?

Comment: @Igor ничего, .done же не сразу обрабатывается )

Comment: @agafron Не пробуйте. Это ни на что не повлияет.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: ага, я уже по всякому попробовал, переменной присваивается  undefined, а если объявить ее в .done(function(data) {}, то дальше ее тоже нельзя использовать, она видна только внутри этой ф-ции